# How to target and count value with JQ?

Tags: arrays, json, linux, jq

From this file :

```
[
    {
        "network": "X.X.X.1",
        "defaultGateway": "X.X.X.X",
        "ipAddressTab": [
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.1",
                "foo2": "network",
                "status": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.2",
                "foo2": "network",
                "status": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.3",
                "foo2": "network",
                "status": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.4",
                "status": "available"
             },
             {   
                "foo1": "10.0.0.5",
                "status": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.6",
                "status": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.7",
                "status": "available"
             }
        ],
        "full": false,
        "id": "xxx"
    },
     {
        "network": "X.X.X.2",
        "defaultGateway": "X.X.X.X",
        "ipAddressTab": [
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.1",
                "foo2": "network",
                "status": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.2",
                "foo2": "network",
                "status": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.3",
                "foo2": "network",
                "status": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.4",
                "status": "available"
             },
             {   
                "foo1": "10.0.0.5",
                "status": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.6",
                "status": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.7",
                "status": "available"
             }
        ],
        "full": false,
        "id": "xxx"
    }
]

# Just an example, there is more lines in my file
```

I can keep the informations that I want :

```
cat myfile | jq 'map({network, full})'
[
  {
    "network": "X.X.X.1",
    "full": false
  },
  {
    "network": "X.X.X.2",
    "full": false
  }
]
```

Now I'm looking for a tip to count and display some values. For example, I would like to display the number of reserved, allocated and available like that :

```
[
  {
    "network": "X.X.X.1",
    "full": false
    reserved: 3
    available: 4

    

  },
  {
    "network": "X.X.X.2",
    "full": false
    reserved: 3
    available: 4

  }
]
```

I've look everywhere and I found no good example to do that...

Some one to show me how can I have this output ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` to count statuses.

```
map({network, full} +
  reduce .ipAddressTab[].status as $s ({}; .[$s] += 1))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pApUlBLhAf)</sup>

You can change `{}` to `{reserved: 0, available: 0}` to maintain a consistent order of keys among all the entries.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use a function to count the objects of each type

```
def f($path; $val): $path | map(select(.status == $val)) | length;
map({network, full, reserved: f(.ipAddressTab; "reserved"), available: f(.ipAddressTab; "available")})
```

<sup>[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IIwu8K6LSh)</sup>

The function `f` takes a path and the status string to be looked-up then gets the length of the objects in the array.

---

With [oguz ismail's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) suggestion to avoid repetition

```
def f($val): map(select(.status == $val)) | length; 
map({network, full} + (.ipAddressTab | { reserved: f("reserved"), available: f("available")}))
```

Answer (score 1):

When counting a potentially large number of objects, it's usually better to
use stream-oriented filters so as to avoid constructing arrays. These two are often useful as a pair, though in the present case defining just `count/1` by itself would be sufficient:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+$x);

def count(s): sigma(s|1);
```

To achieve the stated goal, one can now simply write the specification as a program:

```
map({network,
    full,
    reserved:   count(.ipAddressTab[] | select(.status == "reserved")),
    available:  count(.ipAddressTab[] | select(.status == "available"))
    })
```

### Generalization

Now for a little jq magic -- no references to specific "status" values at all:

```
def countStatus($s):
  {($s): count(.ipAddressTab[] | select(.status == $s))};

def statuses: [.ipAddressTab[].status] | unique;

map( {network, full}
     + ([countStatus(statuses[])] | add) )
```

### total_available

In a comment, a question about showing `total_available` was asked.
To add a `total_available` key to each object, you could append the
following to either of the above pipelines:

```
| {total_available: sigma(.[] | .available)} as $total
| map(. + $total)
```

Comment: Thanks for these explanations !

Last thing, if I want to addi all the value fore .available, can I do something like `{"total_available": sum(.available)}` ?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not too clear.  Are you expecting an alternative output, or should the "total_available" key-value pair be added to each object in the existing output array?

Comment: The idea is to add a variable " total_available" with the total sum of each " available ". So in this case, total_available will be equal to 8.

Comment: Yes, but where does it go? See my previous Q.

Comment: Yes, an alternative output. I would like a "total_available" field at the end of the output with the sum of each "available". In my case, total_available : 8.
here ( https://jqplay.org/s/cE3G5VqhT_ ) there is a "total_available" in each { ... } ( <= object construction ? ). I would like only one total_available, at the end of the output. Thanks again, you're very generous with the beginner that I'am !!